# Using a VisualState to set the width of a RichEditBox to Auto (XAML, C#, Windows 8 App)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, width, visualstates

I'm a beginner working a C# Windows 8 app. I have a RichEditBox in the center of the screen whose width changes depending on the window size. I can set the width of this RichEditBox to `Auto` by editing its own properties, but I want to set the width to `Auto` when the width of the window falls below a certain point. I'm using `VisualState`s to define the various screen options. The problem is that when I set the value to `Auto`, the app will crash when it tries to invoke the new `VisualState`.

My code is as follows:

```
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="FlexibleViewState">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Editor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Auto"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
```

I don't know why it's doing this. I can do the following without any problems:

```
    <RichEditBox x:Name="Editor" Width="Auto"/>
```

But when I try to set the width to `Auto` with a `VisualState` it crashes. Is there any way to fix this or to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to realize, is that the width Auto is represented as a NaN value.  see [MSDN for documentation on FrameworkElement.Width](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width(v=vs.110).aspx)

With this in mind, you can set your (windows 8.1) style like this:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="FlexibleViewState">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Editor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                         <x:Double>NaN</x:Double>
                     </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

If you are using a different flavour of XAML, you may need to use sys:Double instead of x:Double